# i newbie want to build application on marklogic server with Xquery

Tags: server, xquery, marklogic

help me to build this simple application using MarkLogic server:

Building basic  application on top of MarkLogic server(using xquery ) with following functionalities

1. Able to list all the Shakespeare play names in either descending or ascending order, depending on user’s choice  (there will be a radio button for user to chose which order they want)
2. User should be able to do text search on "LINE" element  (an element present in the XML files) and display the matching results grouped by document name ( not the play name, but the XML document name)

   3. Highlight the matching word in results returned from item #2

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend that you spend some time on [the MarkLogic developer site](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn). There's various tutorials and training available. MarkLogic offers on-demand training courses in addition to self-guided training. Look into MarkLogic University as well.

I believe that one of the tutorials works out an example application like what you described, using Shakespeare reference data. I'm pretty sure that example [is found here.](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/get-started-apps)

It's better to have specific questions that we can help you with...